# Quickbooks QBXML and customerAdd

Tags: quickbooks, qbxml

I am working with the Intuit Web Connector.
I am able to add customers using "customerAdd" and by using "openBalance" it creates an invoice.
I have tried everything to make it create an invoice number (the invoice that gets created has no number, just blank).
I would also like to have the item, qty and description.
Is this a job for "invoiceAdd"?
Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to create an Invoice, you should be using `InvoiceAdd`.

The only time you should be using OpenBalance is if the customer has an outstanding balance *that's not the result of an invoice that you'll have in QuickBooks*. e.g. if you're migrating from another accounting platform,  you might have an open balance for someone when moving from the other system.

Beyond that, you should *never* be creating customers with an OpenBalance.

Instead, create an actual invoice. Here are some examples:

- [qbXML examples](http://wiki.consolibyte.com/wiki/doku.php/quickbooks_example_qbxml)
- [InvoiceAdd example](http://wiki.consolibyte.com/wiki/doku.php/quickbooks_qbxml_invoiceadd)

Comment: Thanks Keith, I started off with your framework but it was a bit overwhelming so I made my own. Learned a lot in the process.
I was trying to kill two birds with one stone. Anyway on a positive note I can now check to see if a customer exists before I add a customers and then add an itemized invoice using InvoiceAdd. I have learned a great deal from the snippets you have on line and the SDK.

Thanks.